# Neither the physical keyboard nor the on-screen keyboard work after GNOME sign-in

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, thinkpad

The mouse and mouse buttons work fine.  Neither the on-screen nor the physical keyboard works:

- in the dash
- at the terminal
- in LibreOffice
- in Chrome.

ThinkPad running Ubuntu 18.04.  It's been working fine for about 3 years before this problem started.  I'm trying to support my relative with Chrome Remote Desktop.  I experience the same symptoms she does when I'm remoted-in to her machine.  I have to email her what I want to "type," then cut and paste it with the mouse.

I have no idea how the computer got into this state.  My relative is not technical at all.

First, "I reset all keyboard shortcuts" to their defaults in the Gnome Settings app.  Nope.

Then I tried:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all
```

and rebooted as recommended here: https://techwiser.com/fix-keyboard-not-working-in-ubuntu-18-04/

Then I ran updates (there was an update for Chrome and Remote desktop) followed by a reboot.  No joy.

**P.S.**
Now I'm wondering if something like this happened, how I would detect it, and fix it, but don't let this distract you from providing a simpler/better solution to her problem: https://forum.manjaro.org/t/disable-keyboard-in-gnome-wayland/94661

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what the problem was, but it seems to have "fixed itself."